# autotools: how to include my own m4 macro in configure.ac

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, m4

In my project I have folder m4. In this folder I have ax_cxx_version.m4 file which contains AX_CHECK_CXXFLAGS macro.

Then I'm including m4 folder in autoconf.ac:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
```

and executing autoconf.

When I'm running configure script it's failing with flowing error:

```
checking complex usability... yes
checking complex presence... yes
checking for complex... yes
checking size of int64_t... 8
checking for long long int... yes
./configure: line 7235: syntax error near unexpected token `-std=c++0x'
./configure: line 7235: `AX_CHECK_CXXFLAGS(-std=c++0x -pedantic -Wall)'
```

If I add my macro to aclocal.m4 then everything works perfectly well.

What is the correct way to include my own macro?

Comment: Did you try to enclose the arguments in square brackets? `AX_CHECK_CXXFLAGS([-std=c++0x -pedantic -Wall])`

Comment: The problem is that AX_CHECK_CXXFLAGS function is not included in configure script after running autoconf. So it does not matter how I call AX_CHECK_CXXFLAGS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` is not actually setting up the include path, but it's letting `aclocal` generate the right file. But `aclocal` is part of automake, and if you're just executing `autoconf` it won't be called.

You can start calling `autoreconf` instead of `autoconf` to regenerate your files, and that should do the trick. Or if you don't want to depend on automake, you can use a number of other tricks with `m4_include`.

Relevant (written by me) documentation on the matter is available on [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/autoconf/macros.html).